# PHP- Switching page content without a huge switch statement?

Tags: php

I'm creating a PHP site of 57 pages. I currently have a switch statement in my index that switches out the page content with the get method of my page token. 
Since my site has a lot of pages my switch statement is HUGE and I really would like to keep my code as concise as possible.

I've attempted to make it so when I select one of the main topics in my menu, it goes to another page and has a smaller switch statement there, but this now leaves my index page almost useless because now it only really displays the home page and all the other pages repeat the same format as my index does. I feel like I only broke down my huge case statement into a bunch of smaller ones and had to create 7 more pages. I haven't really reduced it at all, I've just spread it around. It just seems like there should be an easier solution to this.

Any suggestions?

Example of what one of my 7 main topic pages:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <head id="header">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menucss.css"/>
     <title>Main Topic Page Selected from menu </title>
    <?php
    include ('incl/menuinc.php');
    ?>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="page">
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        switch ($_GET['page']){
           case 'page_one':
                include('incl/pages/pageone.php');
                break;
            case 'page_two':
                include('incl/pages/pagetwo.php');
                break;
            case 'page_three':
                include('incl/pages/pagethree.php');
                break;
            case 'page_four':
                include('incl/pages/pagefour.php');
                break;
            case 'page_five':
                include('incl/pages/pagefive.php');
                break;

    }
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    <?php
    include ('footer.php');
    ?>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You could replace the `_` and check if the file exists if so include it if not include an error page.

Comment: Whichever way you slice it, you sill need to map a query string argument's value to a php script. You can use a `switch`, or an associative array to map them, or a database, etc. You are basically recreating the Front Controller Pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern At this point it may be worth looking at some web frameworks to simplify your routing.

Comment: For a more clear arrangement, put the `case`, `include` and `break` statements for each `case` on a single line and use tabs to align them. (Not that I think that the `switch` statements.are the best solution here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For systems like that, I tend towards a data based (not DB) technique. An example:

```
$validPages = array(
    'page_one' => 'pageone',
    'page_two' => 'pagetwo',
    // .....
);

if (isset($_GET['page']) and isset($validPages[$_GET['page']]))  {
    $incPage = 'incl/pages/' . $validPages[$_GET['page'] . '.php';
    // if you want to use a line like this - you would need a lot more 
    // validation to avoid MAJOR security issues,
    // maybe only characters 'a-z' & '_', for a start! 
    // adding a pass through 'realpath()' would also help
    include $incPage;
} else {
    // page not known, do something like show a 404 page
}
```

Now, adding a new page is adding a new entry into the array, and the matching file in the right directory.

An even better option would probably involve classes and attempts to autoload them - similarly assembling the class name (hopefully with a namespace) and attempting to use it - catching an error if it failed, to show a 404 page.

This is very similar to what the various front-controller routers perform, of which there are a number in frameworks, both small, and  large.

Answer (score 1):

this will have security reasons as realpath check is not done.

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])                
    {
    $getstring = $_GET['page'];         //string as variable
    $filename = str_replace('_', '',$getstring);    //remove "_" symbol
    include 'incl/pages/' . $filename.'.php';       //create filename and include it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the contents of the pages into the DB and call them based on the token. This way, you no longer has the nasty huge switch. It's just a simple DB call

Answer (score 0):

Could you potentially rename the files to match the GET statement? If you can:

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  include('incl/pages/'.$page.'.php');
  unset($page); // Not necessary but unsets it if no longer needed
}
```

Maybe that would tidy things up?

Comment: Do str_replace function to match strings.